# How to specify SCNAction to use scene time base

Tags: ios, animation, scenekit

I'm trying to control playback of a scene by using SCNRenderer render(atTime:viewport:commandBuffer:passDescriptor:) method, according to Apple document:

> By default, the playback timing of actions and animations in a scene
>   is based on the system time, not the scene time. Before using this
>   method to control the playback of animations, set the
>   uses​Scene​Time​Base property of each animation to YES, or specify the
>   SCNScene​Source​Animation​Import​Policy​Play​Using​Scene​Time​Base
>   option when loading a scene file that contains animations.

I can only specify the property uses​Scene​Time​Base of CoreAnimation animation. Is SCNAction have any property to change playback to scene time?